# Operation in MS-Access?

Tags: microsoft-access, calculator

Is it possible to view a new column in MS-access with simple operations?

eg: my database has 2 columns

- A: arrival time
- B: departure time

I want to view C column with (B-A)

Comment: How can I display results without creating a new column?

Answer (score 4):

You would typically achieve that by creating a view on the data in your table as there is no need to physically store data which can be derived directly from data you already have.

In Access terms, you are creating a new Query.

Use your table for data entry and your view to read the information out.

Comment: +1 for "no need to physically store data which can be derived directly from data you already have" (true in almost all cases).

Comment: How can I view results data using a query? What is the header of the "temporary" column?